# Import and Export Oracle Data in Excel Sheet in PHP

Tags: php, oracle

PHP,Oracle Error I am Trying to Import and Export Oracle database in Excel Sheet Using PHP But Facing Error and troubleshooted on Google but failed To resolve The  code is given below with error

```
ora-24338 statement handle not executed in oracle
'<?php
$conn = oci_connect('akh', 'spic', 'scan/rcf');
  if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
$output = "";
$sql  = oci_parse($conn, "select *  from mgr.fa_elec_cash ");
oci_execute($sql, OCI_DESCRIBE_ONLY); // Use OCI_DESCRIBE_ONLY if not fetching rows
$columns_total = oci_num_fields($sql);
for ($i = 1; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$heading = oci_field_name($sql, $i);
$output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    for ($i = 1; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
}
$output .="\n";
 }  
$filename = "myFile.csv";
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo $output;
exit;
?>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..

`

```
$query = 'select *  from mgr.fa_elec_cash';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stid);

$myfile=fopen("myFile","w") or die("Unable to open File");

$columns_total = oci_num_fields($stid);
$output = "";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $columns_total; $i++) {

   $heading = oci_field_name($stid, $i);
   $output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";
while(($row=oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_BOTH))!=false)
{

  for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
    $output .= '"'.$row[$i].'",';

 }
 $output .="\n";
}
oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
fwrite($myfile, $output);
echo "Data successfully exported";
fclose($myfile);

?>`
```